# How to redirect http://example to http://example/Directory?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, dns

I am trying to configure IIS 7.0 such that when I enter:

`http://example`

it should redirect the user to

`http://example/Directory`

but should still display `http://example`. Can someone please tell me how to achieve this?

Currently, my setup is as follows (inside IIS Manager):

```
Application Pools
Sites
- Default Web Site
- - Directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this as the entire contents of the default.aspx or default.asp file in your root folder:

```
<%Server.Transfer("/Directory")%>
```

Comment: +1 Thank you. Maybe I am not understanding something. When I do as you suggested, I am getting the following error: `System.Web.HttpException: Error executing child request for /Directory` followed by: `[HttpException (0x80004005: Error executing child request for /Directory...` Would you happen to know the cause for this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can't change the Physical Path variable under the basic settings, you could try a default document in the root of the site that executes the page in the subfolder like this:

server.execute("/Directory/");

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using web forms. My team faced a similar obstacle. We wanted user-friendly URLs and mapping, so we opted for turning our project into a web forms/mvc hybrid. That way we get the benefit of having a routing engine. Here's an example:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(null, "default.aspx", "~/dashboard/default.aspx");
```

That maps /mysite/default.aspx to/mysite/dashboard/default.aspx, but actually displays /mysite/default.aspx in the browser's address bar. If this is an option for your team, you should look into tutorials on how to create a web forms/mvc hybrid. [Here's one example.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you consider using IIS URL Rewrite module, you can use following rule:

```
<rule name="RewriteToSubdir" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example\.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/Directory/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```